# css display:none on everything inside a div not working

Tags: css-selectors, css

I'm trying to make some image based links show up only when I hover over a link in my header using only CSS. I seem to be able to get this to work with images only, but as soon as I add `<a href="#"></a>` around the images the code stops working.

Here are the basics of what I have...

HTML:

```
<ul id="Menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link1
            <div class="hoverLinks">
                <a href="#"><img src="/img/pic1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="/img/pic2.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Menu a div.hoverLinks {
    display: none; }
#Menu a:hover div.hoverLinks {
    display: block; }
```

As I mentioned, if I remove the `<a href="#"></a>` from the images pic1 and pic2, this works perfectly. [Working with non-linked images-jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FlashNoob468/n8m7Z/). But as soon as I try to make the images links, the display:none stops working. Is this a selector issue? I've tried `#Menu a div.hoverLinks * {` and variations of that to get this working, but no dice. Is there a way to make this to work for everything inside the div? [non-working code-jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FlashNoob468/LE6gf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide show images on link hover

http://jsfiddle.net/LE6gf/2/

```
#Menu  .hoverLinks {
    display: none; }
#Menu li:hover .hoverLinks {
    display: block; }
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple, guess I was just barking up the wrong tree. Thanks!

Comment: hovers can get funky :D

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following modifications in CSS

```
#Menu a ~ div.hoverLinks {
    display: none; 
}
#Menu a:hover ~ div.hoverLinks {
    display: block;
}
```

This allows me to use `~` sibling selector on hover.

Comment: Judging by the asker's question history as well as the other answers here I think they know pretty well how and when to accept answers. No need to inform them. It just makes you seem entitled, which will probably give someone even less of an incentive to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Menu .hoverLinks {
    display: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/LE6gf/1/

Comment: Yes that gets the hide to work, but doesn't allow the hover to work. I should have made my title more specific to the hover and not just the display:none.